# React ignores xmlns attribute on svg elements

Tags: javascript, svg, reactjs

I have a React component which generates SVG :

```
const SVG = (props) => (
    <svg
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        { ...props }>
        {/* ... */}
    </svg>
)
```

I'm using this component to show inline SVG directly on the page. I would like to be able to export SVG as a .svg file too. I tried this :

```
const markup = renderToStaticMarkup(<SVG />) // imported from 'react-dom/server'
```

Then I encode this markup and I put it in a basic link element. It works fine, however the SVG file is not correct. React removes the `xmlns` attribute, which is necessary to use SVG as an image.

How could I export correctly a SVG file using my component? The only solution I found is to add the attribute to the rendered markup using a regex, but this is very ugly. :/

Comment: I was waiting for the [v15 release](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2016/04/07/react-v15.html) because I know about the full SVG support, but I found that (yes, there is a pretty much support than before but) is missing for some reason, the namespaced attributes like: `xmlns` and `xmlnsXlink `. I need for the same purpose, use `.svg` as an image.

Comment: An elegant solution would be to create an "SVG" React component with basic svg attributes passed as props and of course include this